# Can a lot of traffic reset the connection of the router?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, udp, p2p

I have created an application for fun, that establishes a P2P "connection" and sends some data through UDP from one end to the other.

I noticed that when I run the application on two different devices (both connected with ethernet cables) in the network, and if the throughput of the application is high and it sends a lot of packets, usually the router stops working. 
From what I understand it completely resets the connection. It's like it performs a reboot. Internet and phone both stop working for 5 minutes or so, which is similar to how much time it takes after a reboot of the router. After that the internet connection is available again.

So my question is, can this be caused just because of the rate of packets that are being transmitted? Why?
If that's the case does it differ from router to router? Is it a standard rate of throughput that routers can support without resetting the connection, or is it written on each router in the specifications?

Router model: Fritz Box 6490

Comment: From my experience, consumer-grade routers are indeed prone to crashing under “uncommon” traffic load.

Comment: @DanielB Do you know if it is because of the firmware or is it a limit of the hardware?

Comment: Its a software issue - flashing dd-wrt on a crap router can make it unbelievably more robust.  If the router cant cope with thebandwidth it shoukd dro packets, not lock up, and definately not reset.

Comment: I see. If you want you can post an answer so I can mark it as answered then. Since its software issue it'll be different from router to router, so it answers my question completely.

Comment: Yes, this is most likely a firmware issue. It sounds like you are overloading the router's state table, most just freeze up. Some just have buggy programming, the reboot makes me question if it is **overheating** under excessive load. (I'm guessing this router is passively cooled) Try putting a small window fan or 12v PC fan on the vents, does it still crap out and reboot? If the answer is no, you have a router that's over heating. The Verizon actiontec mi424 routers are notorious for these symptoms, they don't reboot themselves though.